# OpenCL unexpected type name 'uint3' in clamp

Tags: c, opencl

my simplified code looks like this:

```
uint3 indices = convert_uint3(floor(tmp));
return clamp(indices, uint3(0, 0, 0), uint3(binCountX-1, binCountY-1, binCountZ-1));
```

And I'm getting this error

```
<kernel>:22:27: error: unexpected type name 'uint3': expected expression
return clamp(indices, uint3(0, 0, 0), uint3(binCountX-1, binCountY-1, binCountZ-1));
                  ^
```

I'm not exactly sure how to fix this, from what I've seen the openCL specification allows this uint3 definition, but I may be mistaken.
any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  It should look something like this:

```
(uint3)(x, x, x)
```